# Entity Framework LINQ equivalent of TSQL to include count of child records

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, entity-framework-core

Using Entity Framework and LINQ, how might I achieve this TSQL:

```
SELECT Children.ChildCount, Parent.*
FROM Parent
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ParentID, COUNT(ChildID) AS ChildCount FROM Child GROUP BY ParentID) AS Children 
ON Parent.ID = Children.ParentID
```

Note that this is just a small part of what is already a larger LINQ query that includes other related entities so using a RawSQL query is not an option. Also the Parent table has around 20 columns and I'm hoping not to have to specify each individually to keep the code maintainable.

**EDIT**: To clarify a couple of things, the model for the output of the query (very simplified) looks something like this:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int ChildCount {get; set;}
    // many other properties here including related records
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is get the ChildCount included in the result of the query so it is included in the EF entity.

Comment: Can you share your model definition?

Comment: `from p in db.Parent select new { Parent = p, ChildCount = p.Childs.Count() }` assuming you have a `Childs` navigation property.  Granted that will not produce identical SQL, but should give the same result.

Comment: @juharr thanks, but no that doesn't work because it returns a new object consisting of the parent entity plus an integer which is the count. What I'm trying to do is make the count be returned as part of the parent entity because the rest of the query has other joins etc that I can't make doing it this way.

Comment: You cannot make an entity include additional information.  You can only create new anonymous objects.  And if you don't want to list out every column of an entity you can just specify the entity instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Select Query to project the DB info onto an entity, something like:

```cs
var entity = db.Parent.Select(x => 
    new MyEntity
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name,
        ChildCount = x.Children
            .Select(y => y.ParentId == x.Id)
            .Count()
    })
    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == IDYouNeedToQuery);
}
```

What this should do is return you 1 instance of your `MyEntity` class with the Name, ID, and ChildCount properties filled in. Your SQL won't quite match what is generated but this should get you what you want. BTW you can also sub the `SingleOrDefault` line with a filter of another type, or no filter in which case the `entity` variable becomes a collection of `MyEntity`.

For further reading on this technique and how to use AutoMapper to make it super easy to set up, [check out this post](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/building-efficient-database-queries-using-entity-framework-core-and-automapper/) from Jon P Smith, who literally wrote the book on Entity Framework Core.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Nik P - your answer has helped as a starting point for me to get to what I finally needed. In particular the use of AutoMapper and ProjectTo which ended up giving me exactly what I want, plus has enabled me to simplify several other queries in the process.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes across this at a later date, I ended up using AutoMapper as suggested by Nik P (I was already using AutoMapper anyway) to map from db entities to DTOs.

In effect, in my AutoMapper mapping I have:

```
     CreateMap<MyEntity, MyEntityDTO>()
           .ForMember(d => d.ChildCount, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ChildEntity.Count()))
```

Then in my Service layer I call:

```
      IEnumerable<MyEntityDTO> results = await dbContext.MyEntities.ProjectTo<MyEntityDTO>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: You can always use the naming convention, `ChildEntityCount`, and then you don't need the `MapFrom`.